# A little horn sound when I turn the switch in on position

Tags: electrical, toyota, fuse, highlander, horn

I did not used my Highlander 2008 for last two months, and the battery dropped. I did a few(3-4) times jump start using those gadgets like power banks and it worked. But because I didn't use the car after jump start( only I started it for little movements in parking) the battery didn't get charged.

Last time I jump started the car again and it started harder and a little horn sound came when I put the switch in ON position. Then I used the car about 1-2 hours and today I could start the car with no need to jump start and it seems battery has life on it and got charged again.

But the new problem is that I hear a little horn whenever I put the switch in ON position. I don't know what is the problem? Does jump starter damaged the car or caused some fuses to burn?

Comment: Is this noise coming from the main vehicle horn? Or is it the chime within the passenger compartment? It happens only when you turn it from off to on position and not when you go to ACC mode?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2: It's the main car's horn. It happens when I turn the switch from ACC to ON position. It seems an electrical issue causes a little short horn when I turn the switch from ACC to ON.